# Цикл for и длинна массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, for

мне нужно написать функцию, которая принимает на вход число-длину массива, который должен состоять из простых чисел.

Для поиска простых чисел Я написал вспомогательную функцию

```
const isPrime = num => {
    for (let i = 2 i <= num; i++) {
        if (num % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return n > 1;
}
```

Далее, мне нужна функция, которая будет выводить массив из простых чисел, а длинна этого массива - это число-аргумент этой функции.

```
let getPrimes = (arrLength) => {
    let primes = []; // Сюда мы будем добавлять простые числа

    for (let i = 0; i <= arrLength; i++) {
        // Если вспомогательная функция isPrime возвращает true - добавляем это число в primes
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            primes.push(i);
        }
    }
    console.log(primes);
}
```

Проблема в том, что arrLength в данном случае воспринимается не как длинна массива, а как число, простые числа до которого мне нужны.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как заставить цикл работать, пока массив не будет равен arrLength.

Пробовал написать следующий вариант:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= primes.length == arrLength; i++)
```

Но он не сработал.

getPrimes(6) должен возвращать [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто опечатки...

```js
function isPrime(num) {
  for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return num > 1;
}

function getPrimes(arrLength) {
  let primes = []; // Сюда мы будем добавлять простые числа
  for (let i = 2; primes.length < arrLength; i++) {
    // Если вспомогательная функция isPrime возвращает true - добавляем это число в primes
    if (isPrime(i)) {
      primes.push(i);
    }
  }
  console.log(primes);
}
getPrimes(10);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const isPrime = num => {
    for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if (num % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

let getPrimes = arrLength => {
    let primes = []; 
    let i = 1;
    while (primes.length < arrLength) {
        i++;
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            primes.push(i);
        }
    }
    console.log(primes);
}
```